# How to install rails plugin for vim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, plugins

I have dowloaded the rails.zip file from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567.
and have unzipped it to a folder rails.
Now to install the plugin to vim.

Here's the vim version am using in my ubuntu 9.04 : version 7.2.79.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the files into your vim runtime (`~/.vim` in your case).

This can get messy over time. A better solution is to use [Pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332). Install Pathogen into `~/.vim/autoload`. Then you can add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

And use the `~/.vim/bundle` directory to install the plugin, `~/.vim/bundle/rails` would contain the contents of the zip file.

Answer (score 2):

to make sure it's installed run:

`:helptags ~/.vim/doc`

then run:

`:help Rails`

& you should get Tim Pope's documentation for the plugin if it's installed correctly.

If it isn't, just check the plugin is in:

`~/.vim/plugin`

& the doc.txt is in:

`~/.vim/doc`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pathogen, you can do the work it does by yourself:

1. Run

   ```
   vim -c 'helptags /path/to/rails/doc' -c 'qa!'
   ```

   (note: `/path/to/rails` should be replaced with a path to rails plugin, relative path could also be used, but `/doc` part should be written literally)
2. Put the following into ~/.vimrc:

   ```
   let &runtimepath="/path/to/rails,".&runtimepath
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Unzip it in ~/.vim like the instructions say.

Comment: thats all is it ? how to make sure that my plugin is installed ?